# Why can the margin of SVM be approximated by 1?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

The separate function of SVM is :
$wx+b=0$
The function distance of support vector to the separate plane is :
$|r| = wx_i+b$
And we can normalize the $w$, then the distance can be write as :
$\frac{|r|}{|w|} = \frac{wx_i+b}{|w|}$

And then approximate $|r|$ by 1. So  we should get the maximal $\frac{1}{|w|}$.
Actuarially, I didn't understand **why can the $|r|$ be approximated by 1. Because the $|r|$ is also include the factor $w$.**

Comment: Hi Samuel, I have edited your question. If you feel that I have changed it away from your intended question, you should edit it to clarify your actual question. Can you define your terms, please, and perhaps give additional context for your question, or point to something that has more context?

Answer (score 3):

For any hyperplane in the space, we can always find a corresponding $(w, b)$ that satisfies (not considering the degenerate case)
$$wx_i+b = 1$$
since we can always multiply an arbitrary constant to both $w$ and $b$ without changing the hyperplane it represents.

Therefore, a specific value of $r$ (in this case $r=1$) doesn't really impose any additional constraint on the candidate hyperplanes in this optimization problem.

Comment: Actually it optimizes $\frac{wx_i+b}{|w|}$ to $\frac{1}{|w|}$. But in mathematical view, the numerator and denominator both have $w$. So I can't understand

Comment: The term $\frac{wx_i+b}{|w|}$ can be interpreted as the 'geometric margin', which is the distance between support vector and the target hyperplane. I have shown that $r=1$ doesn't limit the possible choices of candidate hyperplanes, so apparently it won't limit the possible choices of geometric margin, either.

Comment: This might be helpful. [Andrew Ng's lecture note](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing $|r|$ by 1 does not change the optimal solution of the training problem ($\mathbf{w}$ and $b$). It does mean the value of the *objective function* is scaled, but nobody really cares about that in the context of support vector machines.

Comment: I know it means the value of the objective function is scaled. But$|r|$ also include the $w$ factor, So Why can it be scaled like that. Because I can't understand that in Mathematical view